# WPF keep ContextMenu Open

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I want the user has the possibility to edit the header value.
The Header Value can be edited in a textbox when the property IsEditable is set to true.
Then I would like prevent the context menu closing when the header value is empty.
How can I achieve that ?

I tried to handle ContextMenuClosing event without success.

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Menu.Business}" Visibility="{Binding allowUI, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter} }" ContextMenuClosing="check" >
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Menu.IsEditable}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu Width="200">
                                <MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem.Header>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Menu.Business, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150" Margin="0,0,-58,0"/>
                                     </MenuItem.Header>
                                     <MenuItem.Icon>
                                         <Image Source="Images/closed_folder_grey_24.png" />
                                     </MenuItem.Icon>
                                 </MenuItem>
                             </ContextMenu>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </MenuItem.Style>
     <MenuItem.Icon>
         <Image Source="Images/closed_folder_grey_24.png" Margin="0" Height="26" Loaded="MenuItemImage_Loaded" />
     </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>

private void check(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myViewModel.Menu.Business))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Accordingly to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.contextmenuclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) you can cancel the closing by setting **handled** to **true** in event args. Did you tried this ?

Comment: Yes aggree with you. I tried this but no success in this way, don't know why